# UIView hidden property is false even though super view is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

A UIView's "hidden" property is "false" even though up the hierarchy the super view is hidden.

Is there a practical way to know if a UIView is hidden without climbing the tree?

example:

```
(lldb) po 0x7ffba8120f40
<UIButtonLabel: 0x7ffba8120f40; frame = (0 6; 25 18); text = '  All'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ffba8121160>>

(lldb) p (BOOL)[0x7ffba8120f40 isHidden]
(BOOL) $605 = NO
(lldb) po [0x7ffba8120f40 superview]
<UIButton: 0x7ffba811ffd0; frame = (0 15; 100 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffba811d200>>

(lldb) p (BOOL)[0x7ffba8120f40 isHidden]
(BOOL) $607 = NO

(lldb) po [0x7ffba8120f40 superview]
<UIButton: 0x7ffba811ffd0; frame = (0 15; 100 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffba811d200>>

(lldb) p (BOOL)[0x7ffba811ffd0 isHidden]
(BOOL) $612 = NO
(lldb) po [0x7ffba811ffd0 superview]
<UIView: 0x7ffba811fe60; frame = (16 20; 110 60); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffba811d1e0>>

(lldb) p (BOOL)[0x7ffba811fe60 isHidden]
(BOOL) $614 = NO
(lldb) po [0x7ffba811fe60 superview]
<InsertViewer.ExploreHeader: 0x7ffba4de2f40; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (-8 -20; 375 100); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffba811ddd0>>

(lldb) p (BOOL)[0x7ffba4de2f40 isHidden]
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>(BOOL) $618 = YES <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a UIKit equivalent to NSView's `isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor`. I have elected to count a view that's not even in the interface as "hidden" on this definition, but you don't have to:

```
extension UIView {
    var isEffectivelyHidden: Bool {
        if !isHidden, let superview = superview {
            return superview.isEffectivelyHidden
        }
        if isHidden { return true }
        if self is UIWindow { return false }
        return window == nil
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to "climb the tree" because the property does it for you.

Comment: Nice. (voted.) What prompted you to write code for an answer to an almost 8-year-old question though?

Comment: The same problem arose for me. After I wrote the extension I looked for an SO question in which to "publish" it, and found this one. The alternative would have been to ask the same question again myself, but I'm against that.

Answer (score 0):

Each subview has it's own hidden property. If a parent view has it's hidden property set to true, and some of it's subviews are also marked as hidden, when you change the parent's hidden flag to FALSE, the parent and it's non-hidden children will become visible but the hidden children will not.

I don't know of a way to tell if a child view is really non-hidden without walking up the superview tree, checking the hidden status of all the parent views. Even that doesn't guarantee that it's visible, since it could be clipped by a parent's bounds, or it could have a mask layer, or it's opacity could be zero, or probably a few other things as well.

Comment: I am more concerned about knowing when a view is hidden because of a hidden ancestor. I resorted to checking the full superview path instead of only testing the view's hidden property. Awkward but works

Comment: You could create an extension to UIView with a method hiddenBySuperview that would return TRUE if the view was hidden itself, or if any of its superviews up the chain were hidden. (Make sure you code it to handle the case where a view does not have any superviews. In that case the method would just return it's own hidden flag.)

Comment: For reference, on an NSView (not UIView) there is a member isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor.

Comment: @DuncanC Good idea, I went ahead and wrote the extension you're suggesting here, and gave it as an answer. You might want to hammer on it to make sure it's doing the right thing, but I'm pretty sure it is.